# Facebook Iframe color theme

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Can someone explain why Facebooks iframe colorscheme not working?

In fact, it does work with Javescript SDK.

Why doesn't it work with Iframe? Have tried to add ( data-colorscheme="dark" ) to the iframe with no succes.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FAdamskyMotorkylareAb%2F%3Ffref%3Dts&width=240&layout=standard&action=like&size=small&show_faces=true&share=false&height=80&appId" width="240" height="80" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="false" colorscheme="dark"></iframe>
```

Comment: Can you please show some code you are using?

Comment: Any ideas? It's werid, since it works with the Javascript version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Have tried to add ( data-colorscheme="dark" ) to the iframe with no succes.

Those data attributes are evaluated by the JS only. When you use the iframe version, Facebook has no way to even read that attribute, because it is in a document from a different domain.

For the iframe version, you need to pass it as parameter in the URL:

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.
  com%2FAdamskyMotorkylareAb%2F%3Ffref%3Dts&width=240&layout=standard&...&colorscheme=dark" width="240" hei
```